# Is there any way to deploy react website without creating a build?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment

I know we should run npm run build and the deploy this build but what I need here is I want to deploy without creating a build

Comment: What's the reason behind this?

Comment: Actually npm run build is failing because we are using gulp , I am not familiar with gulp. I just have to deploy this. Thats why I was just curious to know is there any way to deploy it without building it first

Comment: No there is not, React is a helper for you to organize code and manage states whatsoever, the browser does not know React, thus you have to use the build script to convert  your React project in a browser readable project